# How can I easily edit code embedded in an xml element

Tags: javascript, xml, file, text-editor

I have xml records with javascript code embedded in an element.  Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
      <script>
  <sys_id>011fb5f68fb679a200b0af5a531815ae</sys_id>
  <sys_updated_on>2010-06-04 04:05:18</sys_updated_on>
  <js_script>function myJavascriptFunction(){&#13;
    var count =0 ;&#13;
    alert('entering myJavascriptFunction');&#13;
  }
      </js_script>
  <name>myJavascriptFunction</name>
 </script>
</xml>
```

this file is saved as a .xml file (but I would be happy to change the suffix if it helped).
The purpose of this is that a command line utility roundtrips the files into a database.

I would like to quickly edit the script element using something like notepad++ - with javascript language formatting help.  Then I'd like to save the script element contents back to the file.

I have considered "inverting" the file and saving javascript element contents directly as a .js file and put the xml elements into extended file properties.  This would make it easy to edit with language support, but it feels like a lot of work and then the files are not easily transportable across OS and source control systems.

Am I missing something obvious?
Is there a clever approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your script inside of a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Comment: the script is fine in or out of CDATA.  I'm really looking for a way to edit the javascript inside the element in an editor without a big cut and paste exercise. (open xml, cut .js code, paste in editor, edit, paste back into element, save...)

Comment: Then, as others have noted, the best thing is to keep your javascript files in separate .js files, and point to them with the src= attribute of the script element. If for some reason you really require the scripts to be inline, then you could still maintain separate files for editing, but use xslt ( or maybe xinclude ) to merge the two together for the final output.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - don't use XML. Use regular JavaScript files or regular html files or even store them in a database.

Comment: thx but database not an option - they need to be kept in file based source control (git or hg).  Natively they come to me in xml.  As said, I could store them in .js format -but would need to keep all the other attributes somewhere on the file.

Comment: Then your most practical way, if you must use XML, is to store them in a separate file. Instead of your script tag, make a src tag and make its value the path to the file or something like that. As an off-topic remark, I'd recommend using JSON or YAML over XML if things are going to get more complicated.